# get radio value together with all the rest inputs

Tags: jquery, html

```js
$('.cinput').each(function(){
console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' name='radiox' class='cinput' value='black' checked>
<input type='radio' name='radiox' class='cinput' value='white'>
<input type='text' class='cinput' value='gold'>
<textarea class='cinput'>silver</textarea>
```

I know to get radio value this way:

```
var radio = $("input[type='radio'][name='radiox']:checked").val();
```

But is there a way to get it **together** with all others inputs:

```
$('.cinput').each(function(){
console.log($(this).val());
});
```

I need the result: `black gold silver`, and not `black white gold silver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just select the types separately like so:

```js
$(':text.cinput, textarea.cinput, :radio.cinput:checked').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' name='radiox' class='cinput' value='black' checked>
<input type='radio' name='radiox' class='cinput' value='white'>
<input type='text' class='cinput' value='gold'>
<textarea class='cinput'>silver</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this -- if the input field being looped over (through the class selector) is a radio button and NOT checked, return from the loop without `console.log`ging.

```js
$(".cinput").each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("type") === "radio" && !$(this).attr("checked")) return;
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your elements in a form. Then you can easily get all the values by using `HTMLFormElement#elements`. Just make sure to **give name to every field**.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form')
const elements = form.elements

const value = {
  radiox: elements.radiox.value,
  color: elements.color.value,
  details: elements.details.value,
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type='radio' name='radiox' value='black' checked>
  <input type='radio' name='radiox' value='white'>
  <input type='text' name="color" value='gold'>
  <textarea name="details">silver</textarea>
</form>
```

You don't even need a class. Of course, you can leave it there if you need it for something else but I removed it to make the example smaller.

Comment: `console.log` should be written once.

Comment: Sure, then just collect it in an object.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to `filter` the `cinput`s by those that are either not radio buttons, or are checked (thus excluding unchecked radio buttons):

```js
$('.cinput').filter((_, { type, checked }) => type !== 'radio' || checked).each(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' name='radiox' class='cinput' value='black' checked>
<input type='radio' name='radiox' class='cinput' value='white'>
<input type='text' class='cinput' value='gold'>
<textarea class='cinput'>silver</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var s = $('.cinput').map(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked") || $(this).is(":not([type=radio])")) {
    return $(this).val();
  }
}).get();
```

**Demo**

```js
var s = $('.cinput').map(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked") || $(this).is(":not([type=radio])")) {
    return $(this).val();
  }
}).get();
console.log(s)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' name='radiox' class='cinput' value='black' checked>
<input type='radio' name='radiox' class='cinput' value='white'>
<input type='text' class='cinput' value='gold'>
<textarea class='cinput'>silver</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below, if the form controls are fixed

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.cinput').change(function () {
    console.clear();
    console.log($('input[type="radio"]:checked').val());
    console.log($('input[type="text"]').val());
    console.log($('textarea').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' name='radiox' class='cinput' value='black' checked>Black
<input type='radio' name='radiox' class='cinput' value='white'>White
<input type='text' class='cinput' value='gold'>
<textarea class='cinput'>silver</textarea>
```